# Two involutions of a finite group either are conjugates, or they commute with a third involution

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Recall that an involution of a group $G$ is an element $a$ of $G$ satisfying $a^2=e$. We say $a$ and $b$ in $G$ are conjugates if there exist $x$ in $G$ such that $a=xbx^{-1}$.

---

The proposition to be demonstrated is:

Two involutions of a finite group $G$ either are conjugates, or they commute with a third involution of $G$.

Comment: You should give more context and show own effort.

Comment: For a solution see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Involutions_are_either_conjugate_or_have_an_involution_centralizing_both_of_them).

Comment: This is Problem 2B.3 from Isaacs's FGT.

Answer (score 2):

Given two involutions $a$ and $b,$ denote the order of $ab$ by $m.$ If $m$ is odd, then $(ab)^{(m-1)/2}a(ba)^{(m-1)/2}=b,$ so $a$ and $b$ are conjugate. If $m$ is even, then $(ab)^{m/2}$ is an involution which commutes with both $a$ and $b.$